# Showing html file with hebrew text on android emulator

Tags: android, hebrew

I have local HTML files with hebrew text that I'm trying to display on a webview in the android emulator but I only get squares and not the actual text.
I guess it's got to do with fonts not being supported.
Is there any way to display non latin text on the emulator?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hope this helps:

[How To Setup Hebrew Font in Android Emulator](http://dannylesnik.blogspot.com/2010/07/how-to-setup-hebrew-font-in-android.html)

Answer (score 0):

If it's simply an issue of missing fonts, you might try DejaVu fonts (http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/index.php).  I haven't tried it, but instructions for installing them on a phone (which should also work for the emulator) are here - http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=480964.